# Shapes.AddPicture adds only the last image - Excel VB macro for Mac

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I have an excel macro, which populate images in an excel sheet from a server.
While this is straight forward for windows, for Mac, I get the images using the "curl" command, copy it over to a local folder ( if the imaage is existing), and use Shapes.AddPicture to insert the image and then delete the local image. For a single picture, this works great. But when I have to select a few columns and add  multiple images, it only adds the last image. Can someone tell me why and how to fix this? 
Below is the relevant code
   =====================================

```
  For Each objCell In objSelectedRange

           If objCell.Value <> "" Then
                UserPath = UserPath & "/" & objCell.Value & ImageType  ' Add prefix and filename
                ImagePath = ImageFolder & objCell.Value & ImageType
                FTPpathtofile = ImagePath
                scriptToCheck = "tell application " & Chr(34) & "Finder" & Chr(34) & " to do shell script " & Chr(34) & "curl  " & FTPpathtofile & Chr(34)
                retCode = MacScript(scriptToCheck)
                str = (InStr(retCode, "404"))
                If (str = 0) Then
                    scriptToRun = "tell application " & Chr(34) & "Finder" & Chr(34) & " to do shell script " & Chr(34) & "curl  " & FTPpathtofile & " >" & UserPath & Chr(34)
                    MacScript (scriptToRun)
                    With ActiveSheet
                         PathtoHD = MacScript("path to startup disk as string")
                         localImagePath = Replace(UserPath, "/", ":")
                         localImagePath = PathtoHD & localImagePath
                         Set objImgMac = .Shapes.AddPicture(localImagePath, True, True, objCell.Left, objCell.Top, 30, 60)

                        If adjustCell Then
                            objCell.RowHeight = 78
                            If objCell.ColumnWidth < 12 Then
                                objCell.ColumnWidth = 12
                            End If
                        End If

                        If vAlign = "Top" Then
                            objCell.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
                            objImgMac.Top = objCell.Top + 15
                            objImgMac.Left = objCell.Left + 5
                        Else
                            If vAlign = "Bottom" Then
                                objCell.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignBottom
                                objImgMac.Top = objCell.Top + 5
                                objImgMac.Left = objCell.Left + 5
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With

            'delete file from the folder
            DeleteFileOnMac (localImagePath)

            End If
            End If

  Next objCell
```

=============================

Comment: I don't have a mac but would be curious to know what happens if you put a breakpoint at `.Shapes.AddPicture` and step through your loop?  Do you observe each picture being added (and then later removed)?  Or does it simply **not** add each picture, but only adds the last picture?

Comment: You have `UserPath = UserPath & "/" & objCell.Value & ImageType` within your loop, but you don't seem to ever reset the value of `UserPath` between iterations, so it will just accumulate content.

Comment: Why are you linking the picture to the file when you're going to delete the file?

Comment: @Tim Williams= A million Thanks- That was the the problem. How will I mark it as the answer though?

Comment: @DavidZemens - Yes, it was adding each picture , but as Tim williams said, it was aaccumulating content

Comment: @Rory - Copying the image to local folder was a round about way to get the image in from a windows server ( accessed from mac). Once the image is copied over to excel, there was no need for the images, so deleted it

Comment: posted my comment as an answer...

Comment: That doesn't explain why you were using `True` as the 2nd argument to link to that file (which won't exist) rather than `False` to disconnect it. ;)

Comment: @Rory. Thanks, I had fixed that issue too - Infact, I used insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
 UserPath = UserPath & "/" & objCell.Value & ImageType
```

within your loop, but you don't seem to ever reset the value of UserPath between iterations, so it will just accumulate content.